# Search a column for multiple words using Django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have an autocomplete box which needs to return results having input words. However the input words can be partial and located in different order or places.

**Example:**

The values in database column (MySQL)-

```
Expected quarterly sales
Sales preceding quarter
Profit preceding quarter
Sales 12 months
```

Now if user types `quarter sales` then it should return both of the first two results.

I tried:

```
column__icontains = term  #searches only '%quarter sales% and thus gives no results
column__search = term  #searches any of complete words and also returns last result
**{'ratio_name__icontains':each_term for each_term in term.split()}   #this searches only sales as it is the last keyword argument
```

Any trick via regex or may be something I am missing inbuilt in Django since this is a common pattern?

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but this looks more like a Full-Text search problem to me. You should take a look at MySQL Full-Text search and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Did you try to use any search engine? Check haystack (http://haystacksearch.org/) out. It supports whoosh which is very easy to use at the beginning, and much more

Comment: Hi Manoj, I did try full-text search but it returns results which have ANY of the above words. Example it also returns Sales 12 months (which it shouldn't).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Search engines are better for this task, but you can still do it with basic code.
If you're looking for strings containing "A" and "B", you can

```
Model.objects.filter(string__contains='A').filter(string__contains='B')
```

or

```
Model.objects.filter(Q(string__contains='A') & Q(string__contains='B'))
```

But really, you'd be better going with a simple full text search engine with little configuration, like Haystack/Whoosh

Comment: If you don't want to set up a full text search engine, databases now come with built-in full-text search feature. [Django currently supports Postgres](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) and you can [manually add support for other databases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55985693/1925257) as well. The built-in full-text search feature won't be as good as a dedicated search engine, of course, but it's still far better than chaining filters for each word.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers using chained `.filter()` require entries to match ALL the filters.

For those wanting "inclusive or" or ANY type behaviour, you can use functools.reduce to chain together django's Q operator for a list of search terms:

```py
from functools import reduce

from django.db.models import Q

list_of_search_terms = ["quarter", "sales"]
query = reduce(
    lambda a, b: a | b,
    (Q(column__icontains=term) for term in list_of_search_terms),
)
YourModel.objects.filter(query)
```