# How to install fulltext.search mysql django

Tags: mysql, django, installation

Tried  to import the SearchManager

```
from fulltext.search import SearchManager
```

Then got an error

```
ImportError: No module named fulltext.search
```

How can i install this module?

Comment: maybe this can help you http://www.mercurytide.co.uk/news/article/django-full-text-search/

Answer (score 0):

[Django MySQL full text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248743/django-mysql-full-text-search)

You can use full text search in django

MyItem.objects.filter(title__search="some search text")

One thing is - you can't define a fulltext index from a Django model, you need to do in directly in a database (using PHPMyAdmin or SQL query)

See Django documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#search