# how to split words that user inserts in input field in Django app

Tags: python, django, search, partial-matches

I have a search bar that is searching in 2 models columns title, body, short_description. I am.using MySQL database. Right now, I am using Q lookups but there are some search limitations that I'd like to 'improve'.

One of them is that Q lookups find only results based only on phrase results that are exactly the same as in field so for instance, I have the title `why python is so amazing?` and I must write `why` or `python` or `python is` in order to get results. What I'd like to get is to extend the search bar to work in the following way:

A user inserts a question in the search bar: `python language` and search lookup is splitting each word and returning all objects that contain `python` or `language`. In the end the result would return object with `why python is so amazing?`, no matter it user puts `python language` or `amazing python`.

I am posting my current code below:

views.py

```
def search_items(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    article_list= Article.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
    qa_list = QA.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)

    if query is not None:
        lookups = Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(short_description__icontains=query) | Q(body__icontains=query)
        article_list= Article.objects.filter(lookups, status=1).distinct()
        qa_list = QA.objects.filter(lookups, status=1).distinct()

    context = {
        'query_name': query,
        'article_list': article_list,
        'qa_list': qa_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'search/search_items.html', context)
```

I've checked this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248743/django-mysql-full-text-search) and [this one](https://github.com/confirm/django-fulltext-search) but the results are not satisfactory because when I put `python language` to find an object with the title `why python is so amazing` I get no result.

**Question**

I'd appreciate any advice on how to achieve the result where I get objects with a list of all objects based on words that the user puts into the input field.

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington MySQL, Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and solved it by adding a custom search manager in models.py, above my model.  The manager has two methods, one for single word searches, another for multi-word.  The query string is split into a list of words using the `.split()`, (see the view) below.

models.py

```
class MyModelSearchManager(models.QuerySet):
    def search(self, query=None):
        qs = self
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = (Q(some_field__icontains=query))
            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup).distinct()
        return qs

    def search_and(self, query=None):
        qs = self
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [Q(some_field__icontains=word) for word in query])
            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup).distinct()
        return qs

class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModelSearchManager(self.model, using=self._db)

    def search(self, query=None):
        return self.get_queryset().search(query=query)

    def search_and(self, query=None):
        return self.get_queryset().search_and(query=query)
```

and of course, declare the custom manager below your model fields:

```
objects = MyModelManager()
```

Then, in your view, split the search string and distinguish between single word searches and multi-word searches:

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'my_app_templates/search_results.html'
    count = 0
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['count'] = self.count or 0
        context['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        query_list = request.GET.get('q', None).split()
        query_list_count = len(query_list)
        
        if query_list is not None:
            if query_list_count == 1:
                qs = MyModel.objects.search(query=query_list[0]).order_by('-date_added')
                self.count = len(qs)
            elif query_list_count > 1:
                qs = MyModel.objects.search_and(query=query_list).order_by('-date_added')
                self.count = len(qs)
            result_count = len(qs)
            create_search_record(self, request, query_list, query_list_count, result_count)
            return qs
```

For multi-word strings, the magic is in the `reduce` function that attempts all keywords against the given model fields.  Much of the credit for this manager pattern goes to Justin Mitchel's [excellent writeup on multi-model search.](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/a-multiple-model-django-search-engine/)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's brilliant. I'd like to ask what is `create_search_record`?

Comment: You're welcome! Oh, create search record is a function I added that does exactly what it sounds like. I meant to take it out, sorry for the confusion. It calls a create method (declared elsewhere) that tracks in a database table what users are searching for, and whether they got a result.